# Different Between type Player and data Player?

Tags: variables, haskell, types, record

what's the diference between:

**A):**

```
type Player = (String, Int)

name:: Player -> String
name (n,_) = n

number :: Player -> Int
number (_,i) = i
```

and **B):**

```
data Player = Player { name :: String
                      , number :: Int
                      }
```

When do I use each one?

Comment: `type` is a type *synonym*. You thus do not create a new type, you simply give `(String, Int)` an extra name. Wherea `data` creates a new type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type Player = (String, Int)
```

creates a new *name* for the type `(String, Int)`. This is not a terribly useful thing to do. A player could be confused for any such pair, and the type system wouldn't catch the error. It's impossible to write class instances for `Player` that don't apply to `(String, Pair)`.

```
data Player = Player { name :: String
                      , number :: Int
                      }
```

creates a whole new type, `Player`, with a constructor named `Player` that has two named fields. This *is* a useful thing to do.

My advice to beginners: just don't bother with `type`. It's mostly useful in combination with certain advanced language features, and it's never very exciting.